# FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample throwing exception

Tags: spring-integration

When I try to use the Sample example given in GITHUB and try to point to my FTP. Its throwing below exception.  Did anyone face the same problem. ?

**GITHUB LINK :** 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp

**Exception Details :**

NFO: started ftpInbound
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'ftpChannel' must be of type [org.springframework.messaging.PollableChannel], but was actually of type [org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:376)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:979)
    at com.farmers.csi.batchutil.service.FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample.main(FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample.java:25)

Comment: Which integration context are you using for your application?  The FtpInboundChannelAdapterSample-context.xml has the ftpChannel configured as a queue. FtpOutboundChannelAdapterSample-context.xml has the ftpChannel configured to be a pollable channel. I suspect you using the wrong integration context file when running the demo.

Comment: Yeah. that was the issue. thanks Luhar.